# Unable to print output in python using subprocess when running compiled c executable

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm trying to build a python 3.9 script that is able to run a compiled c99 program executable and test the functionality. The c program consists of a simple while loop that runs until the exit value is pressed.
1 will print option 1 is selected
2 will print option 2 is selected
3 will exit the loop and cause the program to finish running

The c code looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main() {

    int choice = 0;

    while (choice != 3) {
        printf("\nSelect option \n\n");
        printf("1. option 1\n");
        printf("2. option 2\n");
        printf("3. Exit\n");

        printf("Enter your choice:");

        //Read the input using fgets to prevent cases where the user may enter a string as an input which is invalid
        scanf("%d", &choice);

        // validate choice here - should be a number between 1 and 7

        switch (choice) {
            case 1:
                printf("option 1 picked");
                break;

            case 2:
                printf("option 2 picked");
                break;
            case 3:
                printf("QUITING");
                break;

            default:
                printf("That is an invalid choice\n");
        }
    }


    return 0;
}
```

I made it as simple as I can from what i have now, but it's essentially a menu screen. In c it works without issues and compiles without warnings.

I was able to run the program from python using

```
# Command to run C program
command = [r"./untitled3.exe"]

# Use communicate to send input and receive output
p = Popen(command, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
input_data = '1\n3\n'
p.stdin.write(input_data.encode())
out, _ = p.communicate()

print(out.decode('utf-8').replace('\r\n', '\n'))
```

However I run into issues whenever I want to print the output while the program is running or if I don't terminate it by entering the digit 3. From looking online it seems that p.communicate() will only work once the program has finished running, so I looked into using stdout.readlines() or  stdout.readline() or even just stdout.read like this:

```
# Command to run C program
command = [r"./untitled3.exe"]

# Use communicate to send input and receive output
p = Popen(command, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
input_data = '1\n3\n' # or even '1\n' for when I dont want to terminate it like that
p.stdin.write(input_data.encode())

print(p.stdout.readlines())
#out, _ = p.communicate()

#print(out.decode('utf-8').replace('\r\n', '\n'))
```

But that causes the program to sit idle and not do anything but still run.

I'm hoping that I can read realtime input from the subprocess and be able to end the process without entering the digit 3. For example if I input 1, I'm trying to read an input like this:
Select option

1. option 1
2. option 2
3. Exit
   Enter your choice:1
   option 1 picked

and then be able to exit it right after that.

I've tried using `with Popen(command, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE) f:` but I couldn't get it working, I tried terminating the process as well but the code never reaches it so it doesn't do anything, I also tried to see if its possible to send a forced exit ctrl+c to the subprocess but that also doesn't work.

p.communicate() will only work when the code finishes running which doesn't happen if I dont enter 3 so it doesn't work

and p.stdout.readlines() just causes the program to idle and not do anything.

A lot of the questions that I found already are for just output and not considering doing both. For example, I tried doing this even as its the most common example I found:

```
# Command to run your C program
command = [r"./untitled3.exe"]
p = Popen(command, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)

input_data = '1\n3\n'
p.stdin.write(input_data.encode())

for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, ''):
    print(line)  # process line-by-line
```

and even that doesn't print anything, it just hangs in the terminal being idle not doing anything. I don't know why it always hangs on the readline statement.

Comment: When stdin and stdout are not connected to a terminal, they are buffered, just like any other text file.  The data won't be physically written to the pipe until you get 4096 bytes (or whatever the buffer is).  You can use `fflush` in the C program to force the buffer to be flushed.

Comment: Thank you so much! While I'm avoiding modifying the c file, I was able to set the buffersize=1 in the Popen which seems to get things to work. where I can just do 
```print(p.stdout.readlines())
p.stdout.close()```

I still do run into the issue where if my input data doesn't end on a 3\n, the program hangs when reading the lines. For example, this still sits idle:
```input_data = '1\n'
p.stdin.write(input_data)

print(p.stdout.readlines())

p.stdin.write("3\n")```

it doesn't get past the print statement for some reason

Comment: Which operating system are you using? On a unix-like system you could use the pty module, or likely better, the pexpect module, to run the program. This simulates a terminal so that your test program will look like a regular console user.

Comment: @tdelaney Currently I'm on Windows 10, but I would be open to giving something like that a shot. I'm not sure if I'd need to fully move my code environment for compatibility onto a UNIX-like os or if Pycharm would let me do it on there.

Comment: You'd have to compile it to a linux binary. For the example code, that would be easy. But if your code is using windows-specific services, that would be a problem. Its easy to get virtual machines for linux distros like Ubuntu. Personally for me, once I've written a test program, I wouldn't be running it in pyCharm over time. Perhaps one of the python unit test frameworks like `unittest` or `nose` would be good.